# XAMPP 1.8.2-2 Apache Web Server won't start, always stops immediately

Tags: php, macos, apache, configuration, xampp

I'm running XAMPP 1.8.2-2 on my mac (OS X 10.9) and the Apache Web server won't start. It always get the status starting up.. or stopped. (never a green light.) I already tried to change the port to 8080 or 8888 but it still won't run.

Can someone please help me? I show some images below to give you a better view.

[image: XAMPP apache web server won't start]
[image: XAMPP apache web server starting without succes]
[image: XAMPP apache web server configure port doesn't help]

Thank you!

*(I saw related questions but couldn't find an answer related to the mac os)*

Answer (score 172, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved doing this:

open Terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: Is this stopping the built in apache on the mac?

Comment: I originally tried this and it didn't work, I then realised its apachetl(L not 1, L for Ladybug, L for Letter! not 1!) silly me! thanks for the answer though!

Comment: how on earth did you realize this would solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks...! Are you a mathematician? (I am.) They sometimes solve things in weird ways...

Comment: says could not find specified service for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888222/unable-to-start-xampp-apache-server-on-macbook

Comment: after you have stopped the apachectl that comes out of the box, you also need to find any process that is using port 80: you an do so using :  $sudo lsof -i ':80' and then start apache provided with xampp using: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start

Comment: This has solved my problem, after stopping from the console i changed the port from XAMPP gui Configure option and restarted the service. great Gabbyboy....

Answer (score 1):

After install Mac OS X 10.11 you must reinstall XAMPP again. I'm not sure what is different (maybe some permissions) but that was the unique solution for me when I had the same problem.