# Unable to start XAMPP Apache server on MacOS-Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, localhost, macos-sierra

Whenever I'm trying to start my `Apache` server from `XAMPP` on my `Macbook` (MacOS-Sierra) . I'm getting following application log :

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
```

And status remains `Stopped`. I re-install `XAMPP` and restarted my laptop multiple times, but I'm still having same issue. Couldn't find anything help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76916743/1076483

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Make sure port 80 is not being used (Use `Network Utility` and scan for port 80. If you found any application using port 80, then kill it)
2. Open terminal and execute

   ```
   sudo apachectl stop
   ```

   (ignore, if you get any error)
3. On the same terminal window execute

   ```
    sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start
   ```
4. Open XAMPP control panel, your apache server might have started by now, if not then you can start manually by clicking `start` button.

This worked for me!!

Comment: ahh.. thank you for saving my sanity. I am getting real drunk tonight.

Comment: just to add, to check which process is using port 80 on mac you can use $sudo lsof -i ':80'

Answer (score 3):

Simply goto your terminal and type:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

It'll ask for password. Enter your system password.

Go back to XAMPP control panel and start Apache. 
It should get started now.

Comment: How does this command help ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem and fixed it by `deleting` the `lib folder` in `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/` and `installing XAMPP again`. It's probably due to old lib files from previous versions not being updated properly.

Answer (score 2):

Another related issue, which I faced caused Apache sever failure. And failure logs is :

```
[Sun Jul 30 12:43:58.747822 2017] [unique_id:alert] [pid 9188] (EAI 8)nodename nor servname provided, or not known: AH01564: 
unable to find IPv4 address of "MacBook-Pro.local" AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

To solve this :

1. Executed following command

   ```
   sudo -e /etc/hosts
   ```
2. Then, changed following entries

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localhost
   ::1    localhost
   ```

   to

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localhost MacBook-Pro.local
   ::1    localhost MacBook-Pro.local
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I update my XAMPP app, if you have to do this, you first have to uninstall your XAMPP (save your HTDOCS files in another folder, NOT in XAMPP folder, or you will lose it), and after that you can install the newest version of XAMPP. It worked for me, hope for you too.