# XAMPP 7.2.8-0 Mac Apache web server update/install won't start anymore

Tags: apache, xampp

I am running MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 and I have just tried to upgrade to the latest version of XAMPP on localhost.

I have just upgraded from XAMPP 7.1.10 to 7.2.8-0 by performing an install of the xampp-osx-7.2.8-0-installer.dmg file.

It appears now that I am getting a conflict between AVAST running on port 80

The system was working before running both AVAST and XAMPP 7.1.10 I assume on the default port of 80 but I did not check before the upgrade to 7.2.8

Disabling the AVAST Shields still resulted in processes on port 80

```
colins-iMac:phpmyadmin colinhart$ sudo lsof -i :80
Password:
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.avast 29044 root   46u  IPv4 0xf605aed3cc5db167      0t0  TCP colins-imac:61319->host213-123-242-66.in-addr.btopenworld.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
com.avast 29044 root   57u  IPv4 0xf605aed3d4de9a5f      0t0  TCP colins-imac:61274->64.95.190.66:http (ESTA
```

and XAMPP also running on Port 80 by default, I have tried changing the port for XAMPP to an available one 80+ to no avail

I am desperate to get this working now as I am unable to develop, so any help would be much appreciated.

I will continue trying to fix the problem by reviewing answers to similar queries.

***UPDATE* I uninstalled AVAST and installed AVIRA, and yet the Apache Web server still stops soon after Starting**

Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to the problem having tried virtually all suggestions given by previous answers on this site, was to change the /etc/hosts file as suggested in this response

[Unable to start XAMPP Apache server on MacOS-Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888222/unable-to-start-xampp-apache-server-on-macos-sierra)

To solve this :

Executed following command

sudo -e /etc/hosts
Then, changed following entries

127.0.0.1    localhost
::1    localhost
to

127.0.0.1    localhost MacBook-Pro.local
::1    localhost MacBook-Pro.local

where **MacBook-Pro.local** is the name returned by hostname command in terminal session

```
colins-iMac:~ colinhart$ hostname
colins-iMac
colins-iMac:~ colinhart$ 

in my case the name should be colins-iMac
```

Many Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `lib` folder from XAMPP files and reinstalling worked for me

Check this [SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719132/2317116)