# I cannot start Apache Web Server using XAMPP 7.2.26-0 on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.5

Tags: apache, xampp

I could install successfully XAMPP 7.2.26-0 on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.5. The problem is that I cannot start Apache:

[image]

In the server events, I see this:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Stopping all servers...
Stopping MySQL Database...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql stopped
Restarting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  started at port 3306
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
2020-01-07 11:33:11,210 Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[24257]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local'
2020-01-07 11:33:11,211 Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[24257]: error: no valid servers configured
2020-01-07 11:33:11,211 Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[24257]: fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

Do think think this is caused by an IP address conflict or something else?

**UPDATE 1**

Since I am not interested in ProFTPD, I am only trying to start Apache Web Server and this is what I see in the server events:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
```

That would make me think that Apache Web Server started successfully. Nonetheless, I still see its status as "Stopped".

**UPDATE 2**

See below the configurations that I have for Apache Web Server. I have not changed anything. I am using the default configurations.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Uniform Server Zero (a Portable WAMP Server) on Windows instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Comment: In `/private/etc/hosts`, I am now using `127.0.0.1 Jaimes-MacBook-Pro.local` and tried restarting Apache Web Server but the problem persists.

Comment: Try executing `dscacheutil -flushcache` to flush the cache and then restart the web server

Comment: I used `dscacheutil -flushcache` and the problem persists. See `UPDATE 1` in my question. It says that `httpd started` and that is odd to me because it is not throwing any errors in the server events even though Apache Web Server does not change its status from stopped to running.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems there could be a conflict between the `apachectl` shipped with MacOS and the one installed with XAMPP.

On macOS, if you execute:

```
$ type apachectl
```

it will output `/usr/sbin/apachectl`, referring to the macOS's built-in Apache server instead of the one bundled with XAMPP.

To start the XAMPP's Apache server, you should use the full path:

```
$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/apachectl start
```

Once you've done this, you can go to your XAMPP manager to check the status.

For Apache, even if the log says "httpd started", there might be another issue preventing it from running correctly. Make sure there are no other processes using the same port. In order to check if you need to change the port number because `80` is used, execute:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80
```

to check, if so .

Lastly, ensure that you have the right permissions on your XAMPP folders and there's no other conflicting software (like another Apache server or web server software) running.

### Furthermore

You can also compare the outputs of

```
$ apachectl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

and

```
$ /Applications/XAMPP/bin/apachectl -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

to understand your problem. Best luck!